# Mysql command does not import all data

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to insert some data in a table but for some reasons only the first row of my csv file is being imported.

Command:

```
load data local infile 'D:/BPMAND.csv' into table `bpmand_update`
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n' 
( @skip, `customers_id`, @skip, @skip, @skip, `date_altered`, @skip);
```

My csv file:

```
24108,"2013-11-13 11:00:00"                                                                                             
10865,"2014-01-09 11:00:00"  
...
```

Table structure:

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| orders_id            | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customers_id         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bonuspoints_received | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bonuspoints_spent    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| current_bonuspoints  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_altered         | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comment              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I also tried without @skip but I got the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was the problem. In notepad++ I enabled "show all characters" and it turned out there are some invisible ones after the date. I removed them and this solved my problem.

Comment: I had to use `csvfix` on mine.